# Having trouble installing RODBC for R, clang: error:?

Tags: r, macos

I just started working through R for everyone and I'm having trouble installing the RODBC package. I've seen that a lot of other people have had trouble doing this on Macs as well. (I'm currently running 10.10.5 Yosemite.)

Originally I was having trouble with the program finding the sql.h and sql.ext headers, but I've finally managed to work through that.

Now, however, when I run

```
install.packages("RODBC")
```

or

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/RODBC_1.3-12.tar", repos = NULL, type = "source"),
```

I get this:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libcairo.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libpixman-1.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfreetype.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libreadline.a'
make: *** [RODBC.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RODBC’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/RODBC’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/John/Downloads/RODBC_1.3-12.tar’ had non-zero exit status
```

And I've come to an impasse. I can't seem to find much in the way of advice on getting through this and I really don't understand what it means. I could really use some help!

Comment: Have you check the library cairo, pixman, freetype, etc has installed?

Comment: You can use `cairo-config --version` for check. I currently have similar problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using Microsoft R Open 3.2.4, in OSX 10.11.6.
To solve it I just did `brew install cairo`.

After that I got a different error:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libreadline.a'

This was solved with `brew link --force readline`.
I then went again with `install.packages("RODBC",type = "source")`, and it worked for me.